# Playing multiple sounds using variables in howler.js

Tags: jquery, variables, audio, howler.js

I am a beginner developer.

I tried to play multiple sound sources using howler.js.
I thought find a simpler way to write it using variables.

source:

```
    var sound1 = new Howl({src: ['sound01.mp3']}),
        sound2 = new Howl({src: ['sound02.mp3']}),
        sound3 = new Howl({src: ['sound03.mp3']});
```

I want to play:

```
    $musicbox.eq(0).on('click', function(){
      sound1.play()
    }); 

    $musicbox.eq(1).on('click', function(){
      sound2.play()
    });    

    $musicbox.eq(2).on('click', function(){
      sound3.play()
    });
```

so I tried to use variable...

```
    $musicbox.on('click', function(){
      
      var i = $(this).index();
      var sound = ["sound" + i]
      
      sound.play()
    });
```

I've tried several writing methods, but I keep failing.
Is it impossible to create variables in howler.js?
or just I write it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="musicbox">Sound 1</div>
<div class="musicbox">Sound 2</div>
<div class="musicbox">Sound 3</div>


<script>
  var sounds = [
    new Howl({ src: ['sound1.mp3'] }),
    new Howl({ src: ['sound2.mp3'] }),
    new Howl({ src: ['sound3.mp3'] })
  ];

  $('.musicbox').on('click', function () {
    var i = $('.musicbox').index(this); 
    sounds[i].play(); 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: `$(this).index()` could easily give you the wrong Index. You should use the index relative to the collection instead: `$musicbox.index(this)`

Comment: Makes no sense to use ``sound0${i + 1}.mp3`` that's pure guesswork leaving that `0` behind. One solution would be to use String.prototype.padStart() - but again - that's not the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired [using the `data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) in your HTML in order to store the *key* of the sound you want to play from your `sounds` Object:

```html
<button type="button" data-sound="snare">Snare</button>
<button type="button" data-sound="kick">Kick</button>
```

then in JS (jQuery) all you need is:

```js
const sounds = {
  snare: new Howl({src: ["sound01.mp3"], preload: true}),
  kick: new Howl({src: ["sound02.mp3"], preload: true}),
};

$("[data-sound]").on("click", function() {
  sounds[$(this).data("sound")].play();
});
```

or without the need of jQuery (in pure JavaScript):

```js
const sounds = {
  snare: new Howl({src: ["sound01.mp3"], preload: true}),
  kick: new Howl({src: ["sound02.mp3"], preload: true}),
};

document.querySelectorAll("[data-sound]").forEach(elBtn => {
  elBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    sounds[elBtn.dataset.sound].play();
  });
});
```

this way, instead of guessing the array index to play you can be more descriptive in your code as well. Say you want to play the *kick* sound programmatically, you just use:

```js
sounds.kick.play();
// or like
// sounds["kick"].play();
```